# ReduxForm needs store to be pass as props on tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I m trying to make some unit tests using ReduxForm and I m clearly having problems with the simplest ones like this one.

Actually, I have a searchbar, and when I modify its input, I need the state to reflect that data.

I've written this tests :

```
beforeEach(() => {
      const store = configureStore()({
        searchBar:{
          inputField:''
        }
      });
      searchBar = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<SearchBar store={store}/>);
    });

it('should have a form Field tag', () => {
      const input = TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(searchBar, Field);
      expect(input).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

That should test this :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
/**
 * The seach bar component class definition
 */
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  /**
   * Render the searchBar component
   */
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <Field name="inputField" component="input" type="text"/>
        <button type="submit">Rechercher</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

/**
 * Decorate the form
 */
SearchBar = reduxForm({
  form: 'searchBar'
})(SearchBar);

export default SearchBar;
```

But I've the following error thrown :

```
Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(ConnectedField)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(ConnectedField)". in src/index.spec.js (line 3551)
```

Even if I pass it the props in my component ... (see the beforeEach call)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For testing redux-form you need to have a redux store and a provider.

try something like this :

`searchBar = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Provider store={store}><SearchBar /></Provider>);`